# Rewrite query url with htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite this:

```
https://somesite.com/download?id=someid
```

to this:

```
https://somesite.com/?dl=someid
```

where "someid" is a wildcard. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you have trouble finding which part of the [Apache httpd mod_rewrite tutorial](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/) is relevant?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)dl=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^download/?$ / [NC,L]
```

`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried over to new target URI.